# IBM Mobilefirst 7.1 performance issue to transfer calls from its adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

We are facing performance issue in IBM Mobilefirst adapter. We are using IBM Mobilefirst version 7.1.0.0-IF201807271401. When user strength is increased to 1000 then adapter will take more then 50 seconds to hit ESB service where as user strength is less then 20 then adapter will hit ESB within a second.

Please find below details for more understanding.

App architecture:

App <---> Adapter <---> ESB <---> Database

```
Case 1: Users strength is less then 20 users
Request made in App: 10:15:00 AM
Request reached in Adapter: 10:15:00 AM  
Request reached in ESB: 10:15:00 AM

Case 2: Users strength is increased towards 1000
Request made in App: 10:15:00 AM
Request reached in Adapter: 10:15:00 AM  
Request reached in ESB: 10:15:55 AM
```

We made the best hardware setup for this project. There is no issues with RAM or CUP. We also observed when user strength reaches 1000 then CPU utilisation is less then 15%.

Please let us know why adapter getting more time when user strength is increased and also resolution for same.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have hit upon a classic case of resource contention. You have not mentioned what kind of adapters you are using and your application server - specifically how many nodes.

Assuming Javascript HTTP adapters ( you are connecting to ESB) , note that it has a default concurrency of 50. That means a maximum of 50 concurrent connections can be opened to the backend from the adapter. Also assuming you have two application server nodes on which your runtime is deployed, then this becomes 100 possible concurrent connections to your ESB. This applies to all JavaScript HTTP adapters.

When 1000 users are logged in and all of them invoke the same adapter, then only 100 concurrent connections can be made from this adapter to ESB. Which means the rest will have to wait until the existing connections complete. You have not mentioned the maximum concurrency your ESB can support. Also, your backend. If ESB cannot support 100 concurrent users, then connections will be throttled at ESB. The same can happen at the backend. This means the actual requests arriving from the mobile devices are waiting. Now, not all users will be invoking the same adapter. The requests may be spread across all adapters, and if all the adapters go through the same ESB, then ESB will be loaded all the time and may not have enough free connections available.

Your own observation shows that the system works fine at 20 concurrent users but is not scaling to support 1000. Deployment on the best hardware alone isn't sufficient. You need to configure your application server, adapters, backends and ESB for high concurrency.

Verify how many concurrent connections your ESB can support. Calculate how long your backends take to respond. Find the total turn around time for a request to backend and back under load. And then size and tune appropriately. If you have set a very high number for 'maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode' attribute in you adapter, then lower it to match your ESB's capability. Also, analyze and set appropriate connection and read timeout values for your adapters so that connections waiting for too long will timeout and the Webcontainer thread can be released.

Comment: maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode is set to 600 on each node which is 1200 request per sec

Comment: Set at 600 and two nodes means it is 1200 concurrent connections. It will still take as much time as the backend takes. It is not 1200 requests/sec. Can your ESB support 1200 concurrent connections? Also, what about other adapters? If you set high values in all adapters, and they all hit the same ESB, you are looking at some serious contention at your ESB and the backend as well